# how to duplicate records based on quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am implementing a voucher/coupon system where user can buy one to many vouchers for a given product. For example user can buy two vouchers for buying a soft drink with discount at retailer X. Vouchers can be claim at the same time or at  2 different points in time i.e. one claimed today and the next will be claimed tomorrow.

When coupons are added the shopping cart the Order is generated along with an associated order_item per coupon + quantity.

Once the checkout is successfully completed I need to duplicate coupons where the `quantity > 1` since I need a claimed_on timestamp for each coupon for audit purposes.

In other words, I need to update OrderItem from:

```
id,quantity,order_id,product_id,claimed_on
1, 2, 001, 010, nil
2, 3, 001, 020, nil
```

at in the shopping cart to

```
id,quantity,order_id,product_id,claimed_on
1, 1, 001, 010, nil
2, 1, 001, 020, nil
3, 1, 001, 010, nil
4, 1, 001, 020, nil
5, 1, 001, 020, nil
```

once purchase has gone suscessfully.

So far I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726667/query-that-will-duplicate-records-based-on-quantity) but I am struggling to see the implementation from activerecord perspective. My main worry is to generate any kind of lock or corrupt the table when several users are using the platform.

I have considered to create a 3rd table that will contain only succesful orders but doesnt seem like a good practice.

Here is my models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
end
```

OrderItem looks like:

```
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  quantity   :integer          default(0), not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  order_id   :bigint(8)
#  product_id :bigint(8)
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_order_items_on_order_id    (order_id)
#  index_order_items_on_product_id  (product_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (order_id => orders.id)
#  fk_rails_...  (product_id => products.id)
#

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  validates :quantity, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  after_save :destroy_if_zero

  def total
    quantity * product.active_product_prices.price
  end

  private
    def destroy_if_zero
      destroy if quantity.zero?

    end


end
```

UPDATE:

I am using stripe to process payment so the Order model has a charge_id to store stripe token - hope this help.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: One rather big note: Never ever ever use current product price in a dynamic `total` property. You should store product price in your OrderItem as it is not to change when the product price is updated.

Comment: fair point @BroiSatse - thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I would'nt use the same table for order items and coupons/vouchers. If I were on your place, I'd remove the claimed_on field in order_item table and create a child table

```
VoucherCoupon
    id
    order_item
    claimed_on
```